# Which preposition is used with tolerance in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, medical

I want to use the word tolerance in the context of infectious diseases.

This sentence:

> The immune response will mediate either clearance or tolerance
>   `preposition` infections.

In other words, the immune system will either get rid of infections from the body or on the contrary will tolerate them.

Is it `of`, `to`, `from`, `toward` or what? which preposition is more correct?

Comment: "The immune response will mediate either clearance or tolerance preposition infections."  I would edit the sentence to : The immune response mediates clearance of or tolerance to preposition infections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"Of"**...because you need it to fit with "clearance" also, with which "to", "from" and "toward" will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Tolerance is normally *to* or *toward(s)* something. [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tolerance+to%2Ctolerance+towards%2Ctolerance+toward&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctolerance%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctolerance%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctolerance%20toward%3B%2Cc0) would indicate that *to* is quite a bit more common than *toward(s)*, while *toward* and *towards* are about equally common.

Clearance, on the other hand, is not *to* something (unless you’re talking about having security clearance to some place or files marked top secret), but *of* something: your body clears itself *of* an infection.

As such, you should have two prepositions to be clear. If you wish, you can set the second set of noun + preposition off with commas:

> The immune response will mediate either clearance *of* or tolerance *to(wards)* infections.
>   The immune response will mediate either clearance *of*, or tolerance *to(wards)*, infections.

Comment: I think clearance *from* infections fits more.

Comment: @doctorate Clearance _from_ infection would imply that the body has been cleared away from the infection, rather than the infection having been cleared away from the body. Similarly, you can have a clearance _of_ blockages in the sewers, or you can have a blockage clearance _from_ the sewers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:
The immune response will either clear, or else tolerate, infections.    ?

Or:
The immune response will either clear infections, or else tolerate them.

The gratuitous use of the word mediate, in this context, smacks of gobbledygook.